# Weblogic Multipool Configuration

Tags: jdbc, weblogic11g

My application runs on 2 physical servers hosting 3 managed servers in a cluster. We have 2 Databases that are not clustered. I would like to configure the connection pools in such a way that all managed servers in Physical Machine A will go to DB1, and on failover goes to DB2. Similarily Machine B goes to DB2 always , moved to DB1 on failover. How do i configure the Connection Pool to acheive this desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but a [MultiDatasource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13737/config.htm) seems to be what you're looking for.

Note this is not a MultiPool since that will pick up from any of the pools based on Load Balancing or High Availability.

Define 2 Datasources, one for DB1 and one for DB2.

MultiDataSource allows you to pick up from either Datasource based on Failover or Load Balancing algorithm

http://albinoraclesoa.blogspot.in/2012/02/jdbc-multi-data-sources-in-weblogic.html